# Visual Studio unable to launch IIS Express server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

Visual Studio unable to launch IIS Express server.

I just bought a new device (surface pro 6), copied a visual studio project from old device (surface pro 4) to new. then made a backup of the project database in sql server and restored that on new device. after all, when trying to view a CSHTML file in browser like google chrome, visual studio is unable to launch the IIS Express web server.

what do I have to do?

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. re-entering my credentials solved it.

1. open settings of vs studio.[open settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqv3W.png)
2. re-enter your credentials here and then start the server again.[your credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02UJN.png)